# How to solve error pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm getting the error pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path. I tested my program just minutes before this came up and it worked perfectly. Then I tested it again and it keeps showing this error. I don't know what to do. Here is my code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
ask = input("Do you want to ocr in realtime or choose a picture (r/p)?")
if ask == 'r':
    while True:
        screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(700, 300, 1600, 1000)))
        # print('Frame took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
        cv2.imshow('window', screen)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
        print(pytesseract.image_to_string(screen, lang='eng', config='--psm 6'))
if ask == 'p':
    Tk().withdraw()  # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
    filename = askopenfilename()  # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(filename, lang='eng', config='--psm 6'))
```

Comment: what's your os ?

Comment: My os is windows.

Comment: This is working for me assuming you're using the default install path. `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"`

Answer (score 1):

I have stuck at the same problem in the past, I think you have to make sure that you :

1. Install it from [here](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki)
2. Run `pip install pytesseract`
3. Adding a new variable called 'tesseract' in environment variables with a value of

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe
4. If you run tesseract in the command line should work by giving you usage information

That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple problems for this issue.

Check If tesseract.exe is installed. If not get exe file from below link and install the same. Remember the installation path for future reference.

```
https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
```

If you already have tesseract installed. But pytesseract is unable to access tesseract using python. You can set the path with in the script like this.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell pytesseract where the tesseract binary is located:

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
```

Doing this should solve your problem

Comment: I've tried that too. I wrote 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'. I made sure that tesseract.exe was also in that location. It still doesn't work.

Comment: If you use tesseract outside of python via CMD, does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Then I believe THAT is your problem! Look at the answer below, it should help. Although i wouldn't bother adding it to the environment variables. It's less invasive to point to it using my answer.

Comment: I've tried all the solutions listed here I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I've tried your code adding the pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd to point to my version of tesseract.exe and it works just fine for me. I added it just below the import statements. Try that

Comment: That’s what I tried too and for some reason it still gives the error. The odd thing is that it started showing this error really randomly

Comment: No it happens every time, but it started happening really randomly. Like it was working before and now it won’t work at all.

Comment: Restart your pc?

Answer (score 0):

The installation procedure and the trained data file are the most important. For example, Arabic language requires ara.traindata file. I suggest using the proper language model and the latest version:

#### For Windows 10:

[tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20200328.exe](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20200328.exe) (64 bit) resp.

To validate installation in the power shell or cmd terminal execute:

`tesseract -v`

It will output something like this: tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20200328

#### For Mac OS:

`brew install tesseract`

To validate installation in the power shell or cmd terminal execute:

`tesseract -v`

It will output something like this: tesseract 4.1.1 and also the installed image libraries
leptonica-1.80.0
libgif 5.2.1 : libjpeg 9d : libpng 1.6.37 : libtiff 4.1.0 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.1.0 : libopenjp2 2.3.1
Found AVX2
Found AVX
Found FMA
Found SSE

If you are not sure about the path, then simply copy paste the [ara.traindata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/4.00/ara.traineddata) file in the same folder as that of your Python .py file

```py
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import os
os.environ["TESSDATA_PREFIX"] = "" # Leaving it empty because file is already copy pasted in the current directory
print(os.getenv("TESSDATA_PREFIX"))
# Copy paste the ara.traineddata file in the same directory as this python code
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('cropped.png'), lang="ara"))
```

#### For Linux/Ubuntu OS:

`sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`

The validation and run code is same as that of Mac Os

Also make sure the path is fine.

This code works fine if the ara.traineddata file is downloaded successfully:

```py
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('cropped.png'), lang="ara"))
```

You can follow this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/lGeM3lSdwRM) for details. Here is the demo output of this tutorial which uses all available languages.

[image]